# Spring evaluation language (SpEL) not throw exception when accessing invalid key in map

Tags: java, spring-el

I am new to SpEL and below is a sample workable test that I used for testing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String,String> dictMap = new HashMap<>();
    dictMap.put("key", "value");
    Map<String, Object> rootObj = new HashMap<>();
    rootObj.put("d", dictMap);

    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("['d']['wrongkey']");
    String msg = (String) exp.getValue(new StandardEvaluationContext(rootObj), String.class);
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

I expected that the expression should throw exception because there is no key named "wrongkey" in dictMap context. However, it print "null".

Is there any setting that I can use to force the expression evaluation throw exception?

Thank you

Comment: You check it, if the value is null, then you throw exception manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why there should be an exception.

Look, do we have an exception in this case?

```
dictMap.get("wrongkey");
```

No, because that is how Java works. The SpEL in Spring is fully based on Java nature. So, here it only delegates to the normal Java's `Map.get()`.

To make it throw an exception you should add into the `StandardEvaluationContext` a `MapAccessor`. And that one already has desired logic which throws exception when there is no requested key:

```
Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) target;
Object value = map.get(name);
if (value == null && !map.containsKey(name)) {
    throw new MapAccessException(name);
}
return new TypedValue(value);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! I totally forgot that the Map will never throw exception. I tried this: `StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(rootObj);
context.addPropertyAccessor(new MapAccessor());
String msg = (String) exp.getValue(context, String.class);` But it doesn't throw exception as well.

Comment: Oh! Right. It will throw if you do like this `['d'].wrongkey`. It is called `PropertiesAccessor` by the way!